# How to indent text, for all lines of text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to indent a title and only the first line is indenting.

```
<a href="LINK" >
<span style="width:220px;margin-left:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:20px;"><? echo $title ?></span>
</a>
```

When I use the above code it returns the title on multiple lines (which is right, because of the width) but only the top line is indented.  I don't want the text flush against the left of the width.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is cryptic. I ***think*** you're asking how to indent the entire block of text. If so, simply use padding:

```
padding-left: 10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:block;` for the span. That should cause the entire group of text to move, not just first line.